# jquery: how to know an item is invisible in an aspx page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

If the visible of a server side control is set to false, even I know it's id, is that possible to know that it is invisible by using jQuery? what code should I use, say the control id="test1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('#test1').is(':hidden')) {...}
```

Or

```
if ($('#test1').css('display') == 'none') {...}
```

- The first uses the jQuery pseudo-selector `:hidden`: http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/
- The second just tests the `display` property of the element to see if it is set to `none` (hidden...)

The `:hidden` pseudo-selector checks the following:

- If the object has a CSS display value of none.
- If it is a form element with type="hidden".
- If the element's width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- If an ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

If setting the element `visible = false` on the server-side makes the element not included in the DOM then you can check for the existance of an element with this:

```
if ($('#test1').length > 0) {..}
```

`.length` will return the number of elements found, since we are selecting with an ID we know only one can be returned, so if `.length` returns zero then the object doesn't exist and if it returns one then it does.

Comment: Yea, to test if it is exist is what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try: `$('#test1').is(':visible')`

Comment: I think if in server side you set the visible=false, then no html code randered at client side.